# How to Record Gameplay on Mac Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, recording, mirroring

I am a gamer and I wish to record my Mobile Legends in my Mac book. Any suggestions of the tools that I could use? My phone is iPhone 7 Plus. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your Macbook for recording:

1. Make sure you have iOS 11 installed on your phone.
2. Go to settings, control panel, manage control panel, and then add screen recording to the control panel.
3. Open Mobile Legends, swipe up to invoke control center, click on the screen recording button, wait 3 seconds, and now you're recording.
4. When you want to stop recording, invoke control center again and disable the screen recording.

The recording is now available in your photo library.

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime on the Mac can record tethered iOS devices if the on device capture doesn't suit your needs.